# Transformer model for float sequences

Tags: deep-learning, sequence, transformer-model

I am trying to apply the Transformer model to my dataset, in which, each item is a pair of float sequences. Traditional Transformer use the sentence to sentence and they require vocabulary sizes. However, my dataset are custom sequences with continuous float values, so that I face difficulty in defining the word vocabulary size for them. Moreover, I don't need tokenize my data, because they are floating sequences already, and my sequence length are also fit to 4.
May I ask how can I apply the Transformer in this cases
Example of my expected Transformer model is like this:

```
[0.567, 0.787, 0.234, 0.223] => Transformer model => [0.673, 0.786, 0.777, 0.898]
```

Thank you so much